# $f(x)=x^a, x\in\Bbb Q; 0,x\not\in\Bbb Q$. Here $a>1$. Study the differentiability of $f$.

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)=x^a, x\in\Bbb Q; 0,x\not\in\Bbb Q$. Here $a>1$. Study the differentiability of $f$.

If we just consider $f(x)=x^a$, then it seems that is is differentiable.

$0^a=0$?

We have to consider the case $a\not\in \Bbb Q$; $a=p/q, (p,q)=1, q=2k$; $a=p/q, (p,q)=1, q=2k-1$? Three cases?

Oh, I was also confused about the defition of power function itself also.

Comment: Can you please also let us know the source of this question? How does the question deal with $(-1)^a$?

Comment: The rational exponent case has a simpler definition and proof than does the irrational case. [One definition of the irrational power of a positive real number involves the logarithm function.]

Comment: The function is continuous only at $0.$ So differentiability may hold at $0,$ only. As $a>0$ the differentiability at $0$ holds and the derivative at $0$ is equal $0$ as ${|f(x)|\over |x|}\le |x|^{a-1}$ for $x\neq 0.$